Gazebo Sim crashes on start up on Ubuntu 22.04. in a Virtual Machine
I install gazebo-Harmonic with Ubuntu 22.04 on vmware17.
After successful installation I run Gazebo with "gz sim". The command prompt outputs the following logs...
Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.

The Gazebo Quick Start Window poped up and showed me the information that I am running Gazebo. When I click on Empty and afterwards click RUN, a second window with Gazebo Sim shows up for a second and exits suddenly with a User Alert message from Ubuntu that ruby3.0 has stopped unexpectedly.
Here are the logs from the command prompt...
context mismatch in svga_surface_destroy

Please help me how to fix this error. Running gazebo is very force for me for one of my projects at university. I would appriciate any guid and help from you.
